# Add some characters to regex for hashtag recognition

Tags: ios, regex, swift

I use the pod ActiveLabel to detect hashtags inside labels. It uses regex to define what is a hashtag. The current regex for hashtags looks like this:

```
 static let hashtagPattern = "(?:^|\\s|$)#[\\p{L}0-9_]*"
```

Currently it does cut a hashtag at symbols like "&" or "." or "-" and i need these characters to be displayed as part of the hashtag.
By cut i mean that it does not recognize #word-secondword as a hashtag but only #word.
How does it work? Where do i define my special characters? I am very thankful for any help and especially for an example since i do not have any understanding of regex right now.

EDIT:
All Strings that do not work currently:

```
"#Version_0.53" <- cut at the "."
"#abc,de" <- cut at the ","
"#abc€def" <- cut at the "€"
"#abc$def" <- cut at the "$"
"#test"test" <- cuts at the """
"#test@test" <- cuts at the "@"
"#test/test" <- cuts at the "/"
```

so basically every special character except for "_" causes a cut in the recognition

Comment: Can you provide more examples for what all are working and what all are not?

Comment: what is not working: "." "," "&" """ (the quote character itself) "€"

Comment: What all strings are identified as hashtags and what all are not? post all those strings

Comment: ok add some strings into the question for better readability

Answer (score 0):

Please try this regex,

`/#\w+(.)\w+/igm`

If you have any other strings not working let me know.

Comment: static let hashtagPattern = "(?:^|\\s|$)#[\\p{L}0-9_]*" + "/#\w+(.)\w+/igm"
or static let hashtagPattern = "/#\w+(.)\w+/igm" xcode says: Invalid escape sequence in literal

Answer (score 0):

Add the special characters in the character class:

```
static let hashtagPattern = "(?:^|\s)#[\p{L}0-9_.,€$\"@/-]*"
```

Comment: static let hashtagPattern = "(?:^|\\s)#[\\p{L}0-9_.,€$~&\"@/]*" works so far, but if i add a "-" somewhere it stops working. Where must i define "-" to be recognized as a part of the tag? Isnt there a way to say every character belongs to a hashtag except for a space?

Comment: @JochenÖsterreicher: Add the dash at the end of the character class, see my edit.